# ValueError: Data must be 1-Dimensional error while creating a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kaggle

I am trying to solve a classification problem with a neural network and after I get the prediction I want to create a pandas data frame with a column from the test dataset and my predictions as the second column. But I am constantly getting error. Here is my code:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7I7p.png)

and here is my error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApHGi.png)

Comment: Please post the code. Try to distill your problem down to a minimal reproducible example, in case the code is too extensive otherwise.

Comment: If you feel like some answer solved your problem, you can "accept" it by clicking its checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important sidenote:** Please, take some time to look into [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), there are great suggestions there on how you could ask your question better.

Now for your error:

```
Data must be 1-dimensional
```

That means `pandas` wants a 1-dimensional array, i.e. of the form [0,0,1,1,...,1]. But your `preds` array is 2-dimensional, i.e. of the form `[[0],[0],[1],[1],...,[1]]`.

So you need to flatten the `preds` array here:

[image]

Instead of `for`-loops consider using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to change your code to something like this:

```
predictions = [1 if p>0.5 else 0 for p in preds]
df = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId': test['PassengerId'].values, 
                   'Survived': predictions})
```

Also, in the meantime look into [ndarray.round](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.round.html) method - maybe it will better fit your use case:

```
predictions = preds.round()
```